# I am gettin a null error in the code below for one user

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

The function below is trying to get the earliest date from a table with 3 dates, one for each type of user, care, sales and manager. This is to build up the diary system by first finding the first date in the diary dates. It's working for some users, but in one case the values do not return at and it gives null.

Private Function GetEarliestDate() As Date

```
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dDate As Date

    Try
        strSQL = "Select dT.RecordID, MIN(dT.inDate) As [EarliestDate]
FROM (
    Select RecordID, SentDate As [inDate]
        From tblOrderDetails Where Flagged = 0 AND SalesID = '" & gUserID & "'

         UNION ALL

     Select RecordID, DiaryDate AS [inDate]
     From tblOrderDetails
     Where Flagged=0 And ManID ='" & gUserID & "'

         UNION ALL

     Select RecordID,  CareDate As [inDate]
     From tblOrderDetails 
     Where Flagged = 0 And CareID ='" & gUserID & "'
     ) As dT Group By RecordID"

        cmd.CommandText = strSQL
        cmd.Connection = CnMaster
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim RecordCount As Integer
        RecordCount = 0
        dDate = DateTime.MaxValue
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While (reader.Read())
                RecordCount += 1
                Dim dt As DateTime = reader.GetDateTime(1)
                If dt < dDate Then
                    dDate = dt

                End If
            End While
            If dDate = DateTime.MaxValue Then
                dDate = DateTime.MinValue
            End If
        End Using


        cmd.Dispose()

        Return dDate


    Catch ex As Exception

        Error_Handler(ex, "GetEarliestDate", "Unable to Get The Earliest Date!")

    End Try
```

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but I would recommend using parameters instead of constructing the query in line as you have done. Consider ```WHERE Flagged = 0 AND SaleID = @SaleID``` then you supply the parameter value to the command object. This will avert potential sql injection

Comment: Just asking cause I don't know best practice here, and how to implement, I then have to use a stored procedure that takes the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in all 3 queries additional where:

```
where SentDate is not null ...
where DiaryDate is not null ...
where CareDate  is not null ...
```